# Solving non linear SDE

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

I am a little stuck in finding the solution of a non linear SDE. Hope you can help me out.
The SDE has the form
$dX_t = X_t^2  dt + dB_t$,
where $B$ is a Brownian motion.
Assuming $f(t,B_t) = X_t$ and using Ito doesnt do the trick. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know that a solution exists? Actually, I believe that the solution explodes...

Comment: Hello, I know that a solution exists. Does this already ensure we can write $X_t$ explicitly? 
I am searching for a systematic approach to solve this problem. 
Unfortunately i didnt find any SDE of this type in the literature. Why do you think the SDE explodes?

Answer (score 1):

We can re-write the SDE as
$$ d(X(t)-B(t)) = X(t)^2 dt,  $$
that is, letting $Y(t) \doteq X(t)-B(t)$, 
$$ dY(t) = (Y(t)+B(t))^2 \, dt $$
i.e., a random ODE that can be written as
$$ Y'(t) = Y(t)^2 + 2 B(t) \, Y(t) + B(t)^2. $$
Now, you can find a solution to such equation (it is a [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation)) and thus find $X(t)$ by the relation
$$ X(t) = Y(t) + B(t). $$

Comment: May I ask you to complete the solution ? (or ) at least next step

Comment: Is it correct to continue naively by writing $y'=(y+B)^2$ and treating this like a non-stochastic separable ODE, yielding $y(t) = -(B(t)-\frac{1}{t-t_o})$. This would indicate that indeed at $t=t_o$ the solution blows up as the comment by saz said.